# AWS S3 remove versions not created on a monday

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We are backing up our web servers to S3 daily and using life cycle rules to move versions to IA and then glacier but after 30 days we would like to not store any versions that were not created on a Monday so we would only store a backup from each week. Can this be done in S3 rules or do i need to write something in lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to perform specific lifecycle rules based on a day of the week. I think writing a Lambda function to find and delete any file older than 30 days and not created on a Monday, and then scheduling that to run once a day, is a good way to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks that was my thought just wanted to make sure im not missing something. It would def be a good addition to life cycle rules its a very standard backup procedure.